# Why does the barbell remains tilted to the right at the end of the jerks of Zarina Gusalova?

Tags: muscle-imbalance, olympic-weightlifting, technique, balance, coaching

Zarina Gusalova does [not adjust the grip in between](https://youtu.be/-X4wFI_vvbA) the clean and the jerk. Yet in [her lifts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3Z5MNARs90) the barbell remains tilted to the right side at the end of her jerks. This is especially visible in her first attempt at clean and jerk
at [IWF Championships in 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Youth_World_Weightlifting_Championships).

**1.** Why does it happen?

Observing the marks on the barbell with respect to both her trachea and her larynx it crossed my mind that she might have a slight [scoliosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoliosis).
I also noticed that when she is in between her lifts her posture seems to be slightly more stooped that that of the most of her competitors.

**2.** Is there any room for improvement in the technique of her lifts that could address such imbalance (and with what training could such improvement be accomplished)?

Comment: Adding something under her foot or extending one of the arms further out.

Comment: @Luciano With regard to *extending one of the arms further out*: she seems to grab the bar symmetrically. Do you suggest her gripping asymmetrically? If so - do you mean before the clean or just adjusting the grip after the clean? The whole merit of her way of lifting is that is efficient and so she does not waste time and energy for adjusting the grip during the lift.

Comment: The arms out would fix one problem and create another, as you noted. Why should she try to improve on that aspect? It seems to work for her, she adapted to her body shape.